# Dieharder input file with a sequence of only binary numbers

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator, randomness

I have a RNG producing sequences of binary numbers, ad I would like to run Dieharder test using them as an ascii txt input file. However I haven't been able to do it properly. Should I use a header like:

type: b

count: 2500000

numbit: 1

1

0

0
...

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can just use raw binary file (no header) and run dieharder as: dieharder -a -g 201 -f <your binary file>. Here is a helpful link: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dieharder.1.html

Answer (score 3):

You can generate an example of the ascii input by running:

```
dieharder -o -f example.input -t 10
```

It will basically be something like:

```
#==================================================================
# generator mt19937  seed = 3865342443
#==================================================================
type: d 
count: 10
numbit: 32
```

However note, that dieharder will expect that each line of ascii file is either integers in the range 0  to  2^31-1 or decimal with at least ten significant digits ([details are here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dieharder.1.html)). So maybe in your case, it's easier to produce raw binary files.

Btw, you'll need about 20GB or even more (for raw file) for proper testing. Otherwise, it's hard to say if test failed due to PRNG or too many rewounds (last tests require lots of data and even with 20GB in the standard mode, dieharder will rewound file multiple times).